Parsing this 体言止め with comma
I am bit uncertain how this 体言止め is parsed:

春の香りは桜の花弁とともに街から消え去り、新芽が大地から芽吹く季節。

I wonder whether「新芽が大地から芽吹く」is the only clause modifying 季節 or「春の香りは桜の花弁とともに街から消え去り、新芽が大地から芽吹く」modifies 季節 as a whole. I suspect it is the former because は cannot be used in relative clauses?

It sounds like they've just left off the end of the sentence.  My impression is it could continue as になってきます or something like that.

It's not impossible to see the whole thing before 季節 as a relative clause.

［春の香りは桜の花弁とともに街から消え去り、新芽が大地から芽吹く］季節。

This は would put 春の香り, which goes away, in contrast with 新芽, which comes out.

I found this example here. (The brackets were added by me.)

エールリヒは、［健康な細胞はそのままに、病気を引き起こす細胞だけを探し出して破壊する］治療法（特効薬）を思い描いていた。


This interpretation is possible but I feel it's much less likely. Of course contrastive-wa can appear in relative clauses (a trivial example is 顔は綺麗な人), but if 香り and 新芽 are contrasted as you say, why is it not 新芽は大地から芽吹く季節?

@naruto - I don't see why that が has to be は. There is no such requirement. A sentence like 鈴木さんは不在ですが、山田さんがいます is completely natural to me. 鈴木さん is obviously not the topic of the whole sentence and the first part is not an independent sentence, either. This can easily converted into a noun phrase like 鈴木さんは不在で山田さんがいる時間帯. But, again, we don't need to agree. I just think it's unfortunate that some learners are misled by one popular poster, again.

The relative clause that modifies 季節 is 新芽が大地から芽吹く. Since は is used, the part before the comma is fundamentally a different sentence. Another reason is that 香りが街から消える季節 is not really a nice expression to describe late spring.

春の香りが徐々に消えて、消え去って、そのうえで、新芽が大地から芽吹く季節がくるんですもんねぇ・・。（新芽の芽吹く季節＝春の香りが消える季節、じゃなくて。）「春が去り、新緑がまぶしい季節になりました」で、「春が去る季節になりました」とは解釈しないですしねえ

「残雪が消え去り日増しに暖かくなる季節」「天高く馬肥ゆる秋」とかならいいですが「春の香りが街から消え去る季節」みたいなネガティブで詩情に欠ける解釈を敢えてしなくても、という気持ちはあります…まあそれは理由の2割くらいですけど

@chocolate - それは「春」自体が季節だから。捻じ曲げないように。
